# WP query if in category OR has taxonomy

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to figure out how to query posts by the following conditions:
if they are in the category (by ID) or if they have a taxonomy term. So that on one archive page, I have all posts with a category ID of 12, and all posts that have the taxonomy term 'archive-trading-tools' I have set up custom taxonomy and that part is working. I am stuck at:

```
<?php
$query_args = array(
    'post_type' => array('post', 'webinar'),
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'paged' => $paged,
    'page' => $paged,
    'cat' => 12, 
    //'relation' => 'OR'
    );
$query_args['tax_query'] = array (
    'taxonomy' => 'archive-categories',
    'term' => 'archive-trading-tools'
    );

$the_query = new WP_Query( $query_args );
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

In WordPress a category is a built-in taxonomy. Then in theory, the following should work.

```
$args = array(
'post_type' => array('post', 'webinar'),
'posts_per_page' => 10,
'paged' => $paged,
'page' => $paged,
'tax_query' => array(
    'relation' => 'OR',
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'archive-categories',
        'field'    => 'slug'
        'terms'    => 'archive-trading-tools',
    ),
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'category',
        'field'    => 'term_id',
        'terms'    => 12
    )
)
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Comment: That returns a 'No Posts matched your criteria'

Answer (score 0):

To expand on @depiction's answer, you the 'terms' in the tax_query should be "term" instead of "terms".  No 's at the end.

```
$args = array(
'post_type' => array('post', 'webinar'),
'posts_per_page' => 10,
'paged' => $paged,
'page' => $paged,
'tax_query' => array(
'relation' => 'OR',
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'archive-categories',
        'field'    => 'slug'
        'terms'    => 'archive-trading-tools',
    ),
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'category',
        'field'    => 'term_id',
        'terms'    => 12
    )
    )
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Comment: Per the documentation for WP_Query (https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query), "terms" should be used even if there is only one term.